# How to force Unity to draw button on the top of native plugin rendering?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, plugins

My native plugin makes some drawing in the end of frame. When I add UI button - it always draws above this button.

I tried changing canvas rendering mode - but it didn't help. As far as I understand - Unity doesn't write to depth buffer when drawing UI elements.

Another way would be to render UI after native plugin. But I didn't find any way to draw plugin other than in the end of frame using WaitForEndOfFrame().

I also tried to add a second camera to draw UI - it didn't help.

I am using Unity 5.6.7 (because my app is 32-bits).

```cpp
void RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::MyDraw()
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    // my drawing here

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Comment: Make it unity surfaceView order as top for android. so do you want to make it for android.

Comment: I am developing for Windows

Comment: Do your native rendering to a texture instead of the main framebuffer.  Put that texture on a plane in unity.

Comment: It works, thank you